# What's the best way to set background color to a grid row in a HTML layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with two rows and three columns that look like the image bellow.

I'm using the following CSS properties for the grid:

```
.grid-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20vw 60vw 20vw;
  grid-template-rows:100px calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

I could just do the following to set the background color of the first row to white:

```
.grid-container > div:nth-child(1),
                  div:nth-child(2),
                  div:nth-child(3) {
  background: white;
}
```

But is this a good approach ? Is there a way to color the grid template row directly in the `.grid-container` class ??

[image]

### Snippet

```css
body{margin:0}
.grid-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20vw 60vw 20vw;
  grid-template-rows:100px calc(100vh - 100px);
}
.grid-container > div:nth-child(1),
                  div:nth-child(2),
                  div:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}
.grid-container > div {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        
  <!-- header -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <!-- main content -->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way = use a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20vw 60vw 20vw;
  grid-template-rows: 100px calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.first-row {
  background: blue;
}

.first-row.third {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.grid-container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <!-- header -->
  <div class="first-row"></div>
  <div class="first-row"></div>
  <div class="first-row third"></div>

  <!-- main content -->
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bem naming methods to assign a class to each div row and give each class a color this will give a neat and easy to read css sheet and will work elegantly if you decide to use sass.
for instance :

```html
<div class="container__row1Style"></div>
  <div class="container__row2Style"></div>
  <div class="container__row3Style"></div>

  <!-- main content -->
  <div class="container__row4Style"></div>
  <div class="container__row5Style"></div>
  <div class="container__row6Style"></div>
```

in my opinion this will be the best because its easy to locate a bug if ever there is one in the future .